# Gulp — как скопировать файлы из build после сборки?

Tags: gulp, сборка, gulp-watch, gulp.dest

Пробую скопировать файлы после сборки в build. 
Реализую стандартно

```
gulp.task('copy-from-build:css', () => {
    gulp.src('build/css/**/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest('folder/css/'));
});
```

Когда запускаю по gulp copy-from-build:css - все работает нормально. 
Когда пытаюсь привязть задачу к gulp build - билд собирается, но из него файлы не копируются.

---

Исходники:

```
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
    runSequence(
        'clean',

        [
            'html-njk', //templating with nunjucks
            'css',
            'js-gulp',
        ],

        'copy:js-single-files',
        'copy:favicon',
        'copy:fonts',
        'copy:img',

        'copy-from-build:css',

        cb
    );
});
```

Лог консоли:

```
[10:29:38] Starting 'build'...
[10:29:38] Starting 'clean'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'clean' after 22 ms
[10:29:38] Starting 'html-njk'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'html-njk' after 12 ms
[10:29:38] Starting 'css'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'css' after 6.74 ms
[10:29:38] Starting 'js-gulp'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'js-gulp' after 2.99 ms
[10:29:38] Starting 'copy:js-single-files'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'copy:js-single-files' after 1.32 ms
[10:29:38] Starting 'copy:favicon'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'copy:favicon' after 671 μs
[10:29:38] Starting 'copy:fonts'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'copy:fonts' after 547 μs
[10:29:38] Starting 'copy:img'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'copy:img' after 814 μs
[10:29:38] Starting 'copy-from-build:css'...
[10:29:38] Finished 'copy-from-build:css' after 526 μs
[10:29:38] Finished 'build' after 68 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Андрею Санычу aka mountpoint.

Проблема была в пропущенном return в одной из задач. 
Т.е.

```
gulp.task('name', function(cb) {
    return ...
});
```

Именно он сингализирует об окончании задачи и позволяет выполнять задачи синхронно.